# Installing PYQT5 on windows10

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I used the following command to download PYQT5:

```
pip3 install pyqt5==5.12.0
```

Which successfully installed the package but with the following error:

```
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
```

Then I installed the designer file using:

```
pip3 install pyqt5-tools
```

Which also installed successfully but with the following error:

```
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.13.0 which is incompatible.
```

I am learning to use PYQT5 and was only beginning to do so but paused seeing these errors.
Please advise.

Comment: I just did. Got back the following:

    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyqt5

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs...........................................

Comment: To install this package with conda run: write and try: 
conda install -c anaconda pyqt

Answer (score 0):

Follow these following commands:
`pip uninstall pyqt5`

`pip install pyqt5==5.12.0`